# How to create an hourly arrival rate schedule based on route costs and agent choices?

Tags: anylogic, rate

I am building a model in Anylogic where customers order containers at terminals with a starting hourly rate (which differs per hour), which I load from database to a schedule and then let the customers order at every terminal with the rate of the schedule. When they have ordered, a truck will bring the container from terminal to customer.

However, I want to give each possible route for the trucks (directly or via a hub that is open at night) some costs (depends on time of day and travel time). Depending on these costs, the agents choose which route to take and (as the hub route is partly done at night) at what time to travel. The choices are:

- Travel directly (arrive at the terminal at day time)
- Travel via hub (arrive at the terminal at night time)

Thus, I want to let the hourly arrival rate schedule change based on the choices agents make after calculations. Does anybody know how to let the arrival rate schedule (different per hour) change depending on agent choices (based on route costs)?

Comment: I can't understand the question. The link between "choosing one of the possible routes" and "the change of order arrival rate" is not clear. Why? How?

Comment: @YasharAhmadov thanks for your answer. I edited the question with the two options that the agents have. If they choose to travel via the hub, they will have to arrive at the terminal at night; thus the order rate per hour should change. Is my explenation a bit clearer now?

Comment: My understanding is that the orders can be placed at any time, but you want to change (or decide) when to deliver the products? Also is it happening because you have limited number of trucks?

Comment: Yes true I want to let them decide when to go deliver the containers (when to drive to the terminal, then possibly to hub, and then to customer). I don't have a limited number of trucks but because there are waiting times at terminal (that differ per time of day), the trucks might want to go there at night.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers, you don't really need to *change the hourly order rate schedule*, rather you need to *choose when to deliver* the containers to the customers. For this, place the arrived orders in a queue and process them with FIFO principle (or LIFO, whichever priority you assign them).

But if you insist on having different hourly order rates, you can use the following approach. So, if you want to distribute 10 arrivals during an hour, you can use exponential(10) as the interarrival distribution. Please see the screenshot below. I update the variable `trucks1` dynamically during the simulation to have different number of arrivals for different hours.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I agree that the order rate does maybe not have to change. But rather the rate of the trucks that start to actually deliver. I now also have something like your picture. However, is it possible to let the arrival rate distribution depend on the choices agents make? Or is it always a distribution that is has to be set before running the model?

Comment: No, you can update it dynamically in the course of the simulation. In the screenshot above, you can type a variable name into the **Interarrival time** or **Rate** cell which will update the arrival structure in the Source block.

Comment: Thanks! I now have that and the variable inside the **Rate** cell is actually a **Schedule**, as the rate differs per hour. But now I want to let agents decide (based on costs) whether to deliver at day or night, dus let them change the arrival rate Schedule. But I don't know if that is possible? (maybe I have to think a bit more how I want this to happen exactly)

Comment: You can deactivate this schedule arrival rate at some point in the simulation and overwrite with whatever schedule your agents decide.